# How to find correlation between two datasets in ml

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, correlation, statsmodels

'How to find correlation between two  different datasets in ml'?
how to find ow this datasets are correlated are not?
example below dataset which has different columns names also

df1
gene s1 s2 s3
1    a  b  c
2    f  a
3    f g

df2
gen1 s11 s12 s4
s    r    g  y
par  p1   rr uu

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to find correlations between two datasets.

A correlation is defined between only two variables  at a time.

So you are probably looking for correlations between all pairs of variables in your dfs.

Try

```py
df1[col1_name].corr(df2[col3_name])
```